# Only an absolute URI can be used as a base address

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, contracts

Please help getting exception at `using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService.HelloService)))` in the below code

> Exception : Only an absolute URI can be used as a base address

### WCF Host Application

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService.HelloService)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service Started");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

### Contract Implementation

```
    public class HelloService : IHelloService
    {
        public string GetMessage(string Name)
        {
            return "Hello" + Name;
        }
    }
```

### Contract

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetMessage(string Name);
    }
```

### App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloService.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/HelloService"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp//localhost:8090/HelloService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you know what a URI is? Do you know what an absolute URI is? Do you see any URIs in what you posted? Are any of them not absolute? Pay especial attention to any which are base addresses.

Comment: just encountered with same problem from kudVenkat tutorials. thanks to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are missing a colon (`:`):

```
<add baseAddress="net.tcp//localhost:8090/HelloService"/>
```

should be

```
<add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090/HelloService"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<endpoint address="HelloService"...
```

Should be

```
<endpoint address="/HelloService"...
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do I need to write endpoint address="/HelloService" and baseAddress="http://localhost:8080"

Comment: Yes I believe so, although you should be able to specify the http or the net.tcp.

Comment: I think it takes baseaddress + endpoint address as absolute address...so in my case it will be http://localhost:8080/HelloService but its not working

Answer (score 0):

In short this is Error related to base address.so, please check whether you have entered base address properly or not.

Error:

```
<add baseAddress=" &quot;http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibraryShop/IStudent/&quot;&gt;" />
```

Solved:

```
<add baseAddress=" http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibraryShop/IStudent/" />
```